# Cordova AngularJS How to free Controllers from RAM?

Tags: android, html, angularjs, cordova

I am running Cordova AngularJS App on 7'' Android Tablet.
The App has three controllers : RootController , TheatersController , SettingsController

```
pomidoroApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/',
    {
        controller: 'RootController',
        templateUrl: 'views/RootControllerView.html'
    })
    .when('/theaters',
    {
        controller: 'TheatersController',
        templateUrl: 'views/TheatersControllerView.html'
    })
    .when('/settings',
    {
        controller: 'SettingsController',
        templateUrl: 'views/SettingsControllerView.html'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
```

});

```
pomidoroApp.controller('RootController', function($scope,$window,$location){    
$scope.recommendedMovies = [];
init();
$scope.someFunction = function() {
     $location.path("/theaters");
            };
function init(){    
};
```

});

```
pomidoroApp.controller('TheatersController', function($scope,theatersFactory,$window,$location){ 
$scope.theaters = [];
init();
$scope.someFunction2 = function() {
     $location.path("/");
           };   
function init(){
    $scope.theaters = theatersFactory.getTheaters();
}
```

});

```
pomidoroApp.controller('SettingsController', function($scope){
```

});

RootControllerView.html :

```
<div class="content">
<ul class="list">
<button type="button" style="font-size:38px;" ng-click="someFunction()">Click Me!</button>
  <li class="list-divider">Recommended movies</li>
  <li ng-show="!ready">
    Receiving data...
  </li>
  <li ng-show="ready" ng-repeat="movie in recommendedMovies | filter:name">
    <a href="#/theaters">
      <div><img style="float:left; width:120px; height:177px; margin-right:10px;"class="movieimg" src="{{movie.posters.profile}}" /><strong style="font-size:18px;">{{movie.title}}</strong><p style="font-size:16px;">{{movie.critics_consensus}}</p></div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>   
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

TheatersControllerView.html :

```
<div class="content">
<button type="button" style="font-size:38px;" ng-click="someFunction2()">Click Me 2!</button>
<ul class="list
  <li class="list-divider">Theaters nearby</li>
  <li data-ng-repeat="theater in theaters">
    <a href="#">
      <strong>{{theater.name}}</strong>
      <p>{{theater.address}}</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In RootControllerView.html there is button that opens  TheatersControllerView.html  with function someFunction() .
In TheatersControllerView.html  there is button that opens  RootControllerView.html  with function someFunction2() .
Every time RootControllerView.html and TheatersControllerView.html  are shown by the 
someFunction()  and someFunction2() ,  the RAM used by the App is increasing.

The name of the App is HelloCorodva , here is the RAM usage of the App :
[image of RAM usage of the App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AgmK.png)

How to decrease RAM usage of the App ?
How to free from RAM RootController or TheatersController ?